# Datemin for bootstrap-datepicker does not work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Can't find a way to set a minDate and by the way a maxDate for bootstrap-datepicker v1.6.1.

What I tried:

```
$("#dateStart").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    startView: 2
});

$("#dateEnd").datepicker({
    minDate: "25/02/2016",
    startView: 2
});
```

An example here: http://www.bootply.com/iNV8YltUmf

What is the right way to set minDate and maxDate ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, they are always the same. Whatever what I put to this values, I can set a date before `minDate` or after `maxDate`. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the documentation that is provided with your bootply.. there are not any options that include `minDate` and `maxDate`... But there are `startDate` and `endDate`.

So your code should look like this:

```
$("#dateStart").datepicker({
    startDate: '10/01/2016', // as an example
    startView: 2
});

$("#dateEnd").datepicker({
    endDate: '10/06/2016', // as an example
    startView: 2
});
```

Here is your [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xK2t6qCCit) to show you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't know where I saw minDate and maxDate instead of startDate and endDate.

Comment: @LondonSmith `minDate` and `maxDate` are options for the jQuery UI Datepicker.  Not the bootstrap datepicker.  That is most likely where you picked that up from.  But glad I was able to help!